# User puts bounty on a question then add an answer: what should I do about this?

Tags: discussion

I was about the answer this question ([Delete Playlists From Groove Music App?](https://superuser.com/questions/832538/delete-playlists-from-groove-music-app)) 
when the author of the question answered his question and it was essentially the same as my to-be answer. His answer worked for me so I've got really nothing to add.

My question is: should I just post my answer anyway? Maybe give it a tweak or 2? I feel like he gave the bounty and then just prevented me from getting the bounty. Is that fair? Also, what happens if there is only one answer (that doesn't work) and his, how will he award the bounty? After all, he can't award himself and would definitely not be in favor of giving a wrong answer 50 points.

Comment: "His answer worked for me so I've got really nothing to add." - You should then upvote the answer that worked and leave a comment.  If you have nothing to add then you shouldn't submit a new answer.  Given the question itself is a year old, the purpose of the bounty, was draw attention to it so those with the problem could easily find it.

Comment: @JakeGould - I am not sure I agree if an answer isn't a duplicate if its not 100% verbatim.  If the answer indicates to perform the same action, but it goes through three difference user interfaces to do so, the end action is still the same.  In the end, RookieTEC9 is asking if he should submit an answer, that is literally the same solution as what Louis submitted.  *There is literally only one way to reset Groove Music playlist though its user interface.*  Yes;  I am being specific to illustrate a point.  Some actions simply should not be stated in different ways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> answer worked for me so I've got really nothing to add.
>   should I just post my answer anyway

If there's nothing to add, I don't think an answer should be added because it'll just lead to duplication.

> Maybe give it a tweak or 2

If you can you can add answer an answer which is pretty different, then sure.

> I feel like he gave the bounty and then just prevented me from getting the bounty. Is that fair

You arrive at this conclusion without even having posted an answer, not really sure how it makes sense. He doesn't know you're going to post an answer, he found an answer to his old question and posted an answer. Self answers are encouraged here.

> Also, what happens if there is only one answer (that doesn't work) and his, how will he award the bounty?

It's up to the bounty started, either bounty is not awarded or if left as is, bounty will expire **provided no answers** which result in bounty being auto awarded exist

Comment: @Ramhound yes - I make that exception in the last statement, edited it to make more clear